# Is there currently a way to get Emacs muse-mode to output rtf,odt or doc format?

Tags: emacs, rtf, doc, odt

[Muse](http://mwolson.org/projects/EmacsMuse.html) is a special mode in emacs that can be used as a wiki. It has multiple output formats like static HTML pages, LaTeX, PDF etc.

But sometimes I need to output something that less tech-savvy people can edit/correct and send back to me.

I think either RTF, ODT or DOC would do the trick.

My problem is that muse only supports HTML, LaTeX, TexInfo and XML out of the box.

Implementing an own output format is currently not an option as I cannot program in elisp and learning it would take too much time.

I searched for a way to convert to or use markdown as [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert to RTF. But I found only the following [discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-wiki-discuss/2006-03/msg00195.html) that does not solve my problem.

My last resort would be to convert to HTML and then to RTF, ODT or DOC but AFAIK the results are far from great.

It would appreciate a solution that can be automated (with custom scripts).

Comment: You may want to consider migrating to [orgmode](http://orgmode.org/). It has ODT export.

Comment: You are right about that. freenode #emacs suggested the same. It would still be cool to be able to use muse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that importing of HTML into MS Word (or compatible processor) should work. As I remember, OpenOffice had some scripting support, so you can launch it, and perform some commands inside it.

Another way - writing RTF export backend, it shouldn't be too complicated, although it could be too much details to be taken into account. If you'll go this way, please write to muse mailing list, and I'll try to help you

Comment: +1 for really trying to help me :). If no better answer comes up in the next few days I will accept yours.

Comment: Write to mailing list or directly to me - I have access to muse repository (as maintainer), so we could try to make some code for it. But I need more requirements - will you use non-ASCII characters, etc.

Comment: another idea - adapt source code from org-mode for muse - I'll look how it could be done...

Comment: I had the idea to just output markdown files so I can use pandoc. I guess converting muse to markdown should be easy. I will look into that after next Monday.